# Displaying img in Angular form gives "No value accessor for form control with unspecified name attribute"

Tags: html, angular

I'm displaying a set of icons on top of an image in my ngForm. When dragging the icons around, I save the new location when form is submitted. Works fine but I get an annoying error when the page is displayed.

**Error**

No value accessor for form control with unspecified name attribute

**app.component.html**

```
  <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #settingsForm="ngForm">
        <img #maplocations *ngFor="let loc of locations" class="map-icon" 
             [src]="loc.getMapImage()"
             [style.left.px]="loc.mapleft" [style.top.px]="loc.maptop"
             data-html="true"/>

  </form>
```

**app.component.ts**
I include the NgForm in my component

```
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
```

Why does it complain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I think I found the error... The error was not in the *ngFor as the error details tried to say. It was with a label further down the page:

```
<label [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" [(ngModel)]="selectedLocation.name"></label>
```

Removed the label and now the error is gone.